# Enter an information page in top menu in OpenCart 3.0.x

Tags: php, html, twig, opencart, opencart-3

All the help for OpenCart on internet is on `*.tpl` files...
But OpenCart is updated now so the basic problem I'm facing is that I want to add an information page 'aboutus' in top menu. There's no HTML view which I can change so, I've a `.twig` file which only let categories show in top menu
as follows:

```
{% if categories %}
<div class="container">
  <nav id="menu" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">{{ text_category }}</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars">    </i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category.children %}


          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-inner"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {% for child in children %}
                <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endfor %}</div>
     <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all}}{{category.name }}</a> </div>

        </li>

        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>

       {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

       <li><a href="{{ information.href }}">{{ information.href }}</a></li>

    </ul>

      </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="{{ localhost/ghazi/upload/about_us }}">About US</a></li>

    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

and the controller is menu.php as follows:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonMenu extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('common/menu');

        // Menu
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('catalog/information');
        $data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category['top']) {
                // Level 2
                $children_data = array();

                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $filter_data = array(
                        'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true
                    );

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                    );
                }

                // Level 1
                $data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name'=> $category['name'],
                    'children' => $children_data,
                    'column'=> $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                 'href'=>$this->url->link('product/category','path='.category['category_id'])
                );

            }
        }


        return $this->load->view('common/menu', $data);
        }
        }
```

I just want to show about us page in top menu

Comment: Adjusting the controller to include the information pages could lead to other information pages that you may not want to display on the top menu showing up. If you only want to add a single information page, why not hard-code the link in the menu?

Comment: can u tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since editing the controller to show a page is, in effect, similar to editing the template in that you're adjusting the code, I feel the simplest route would be to hard-code the URL on the `twig` file. Assuming you're going to add the menu-item at the end of the existing menu, you can try the code below:

```
{% if categories %}
<div class="container">
  <nav id="menu" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">{{ text_category }}</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category.children %}
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.name }}</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-inner"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {% for child in children %}
                <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endfor %}</div>
            <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a> </div>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <li><a href="http://storeURL/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4">About Us</a></li>  
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Please confirm the ID of the information page is indeed "4" and change `storeURL` to that of your store.

We could take it a step further and include the storeURL in the controller file and then reference that in the menu but I feel this is additional work that serves no real benefit, especially if you only want to show ONE information page in the top menu.

Comment: "http://localhost/ghazi/upload/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4" used this but about us still not showing in menu ....               this url is working fine for about us page i've checked it

Comment: You need to refresh your cache, in the admin, look for the blue button under the Logout button at the top, click this and disable cache while working on the site

Comment: You’re welcome, is the URL meant to include “uploads?”

Comment: Just double check the URL and test on hour side to be sure because the URL you sent in your first comment included it

Comment: i'm currently working on wamp server and the name of website's folder is upload that's why its in url..

Comment: Ahh, I should've figured that out! Good luck